# How can I merge my user profiles?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have two accounts on Stack Overflow. The other one is [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737817/nikunj-banka). How can I merge the two profiles and remove this profile?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

If you don't follow the instructions there, you're going to end up making this much more tedious than it really needs to be.

Then click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and select the

> I need to merge user profiles

option.

Fill out the details of both profiles and hit "submit". The process can take a while.

But again, make sure you first read [the Help Centre page on merging accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I have already tried this option 8 hours back. But the accounts havent been merged till now. Is there some other way also?

Comment: Yes - [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) and follow the instructions. It'll speed things up considerably. Then, give it at least 24 hours, up to 48 - there are only a few of us handling these requests, and some of us are *disgustingly* lazy.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. Done this on both the profiles. Please merge them now.

Comment: I have requested to merge two of my accounts too. I have received emails for the confirmation. After I have clicked the confirmation link, it asked me to login to one of the profiles to continue. Still nothing happened. Apparently, there should be an option popping up to merge two of my profiles when i login to one of my profiles. Nothing has come up so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @meandyxtreme - I'm not the person to ask about this. Email the team or raise another contact issue.

Comment: Sorry about that friend. Should have replied to @Shog9 's comment. Apparently, he's one of the Community managers.

Comment: Send a note to [/contact](/contact) @meandyxtreme - we'll get it sorted out.

Comment: @ChrisF If both accounts have different points then what will happen to them ,like suppose if one account have 1000 score for stackoverflow and 0 for askubuntu and other one with 100 score for stackoverflow and 100 for askubuntu then will the new merged account have 1100 for stackoverflow and 100 for askubuntu ? is it ?

Comment: @Shashi you are basically correct. There are cases where you might not end up with the sum of the points, you can only have one association bonus for example.

Comment: I have no way to locate the "other" account to fill in the form. I didn't create 2 accounts, how can i reach the other account to provide the url? I'm also unable to found a way to login into the "other" account.