# What are the rules for merging accounts?

Tags: discussion

I have recently discovered that I have two accounts. One is about 6 months old, no rep, but has some answers and one edit. And the other I have made more recently - because I didn't remember how I registered the first. But I would prefer the second account.

So, why would the merge option suggest that it would keep the old account and move all the rep from the new account? Is there anything I can do to keep the new account instead? Or should I just accept the fact that I should be using the old one from now on?

P.S. I have read multiple answers to questions regarding account merge here, on SO meta, I have read the help topic - nothing explains why the system would want to keep my old, inactive account (yes, I know I did login yesterday to it, while trying to figure out what my account credentials were - this is the time I realized I had two accounts). It would make more sense to keep the active account instead.

So I am just asking how the system works and how it picks the account to be active:

- is it the oldest account?
- is it based on the first link you clicked (from the ones it send to each email once you initiate the merge procedure)?
- is it random?

I actually don't feel like pressing the OK button to merge the accounts into the old one.

Comment: OK. I can see that somebody already downvoted my question - I would wonder what the reason for that may be - maybe I didn't phrase it well enough? If so, I am willing to improve it, if I know how. 
None of the other posts I read about merging accounts, nor the help topic did explain how and why the merge is done. It would seem more logical to me that the active account, with more rep and everything would remain active. And not the opposite. So I am not sure whether I did something wrong or there is a rule to keep the oldest account alive (which doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Never mind Meta voting, it can be arbitrary. Re account merging, though, I'm not sure whether there is actually anything to "keep" that you can't change later (like the name, or the gravatar, or the E-Mail address) - except for the numeric user ID. Is that really so important?

Comment: The gravatar is not important. I kept the standard one anyway. The email address is more important to me - when the currently active account is closed, will it allow me to use the email address from it or will it be blocked? Anyway, if I could change everything as it is in the active account, it is not a big deal. But still, the question on why would the system prefer inactive account to an active and more complete one is a mystery to me.  Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @MariaDeleva why not just add the email you want to keep to both accounts?

Comment: @RobertLongson, it is not just the email - the other account is practically empty - so I should make a lot of edits to make it look like this one. I admit, I am lazy. :) But it just seems illogical. I know that I am a woman and should not be thinking logically ;) but I can't help it. :)

Comment: Follow the steps [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256689), and ask that they be merged in a certain way.

Comment: @Laurel - I did this steps. Except I didn't click OK at the last step. Because it simply seemed illogical to keep my inactive account and delete my active one. Even the comment I left on the form that I want this account to be left active didn't seem to help. I guess the way the system decides which account is worthy will remain a mystery...

Comment: @MariaDeleva Laurel said *"and ask that they be merged in a certain way"*  - so when you contacted SE, you mentioned you want to keep the newer account, and they said, "No way, you must keep your old account" ..?

Comment: There is actually no human involved in the process until now - I filled in the form for merging the accounts, including a comment, where I stated which account I wanted, then it sent two emails - one to each registered email address, I clicked on the confirmation links, and the message said: "Your [active] account will be deleted and all the [...] will be merged into your [inactive] account. Click OK." The wording was probably different, but that was pretty much the meaning. So I was just left puzzled and I still haven't clicked OK. And the account I requested the merge from was the active one