# How do I log out from StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, logout

I tried to recover my password since StackOverflow no longer supports to login with anything but Google and Facebook.

As a result, my 240K points are now gone. There is no log out button, so I can't try to login again with Google. I can't find a cookie either.

How do I log out and how do I get my old profile back?

Note: I can't ask on Meta since I don't have enough points for that (1 at the time of writing and I'd need 5).

Comment: You got 240k points in SO, and you don't know about StackOverflow Meta?

Comment: @Fustigador I can't post on Meta since I would need 5 points for that and I have only 1.

Comment: If you need to merge the new account or old account on other mail address : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256689/how-to-merge-user-profiles

Answer (score 7):

What do you mean there is no `logout`? Yes there is.

[image]

Go to the 3 bars menu, where you can choose your community, and there, `help`, `chat`, and most importantly, `log out`.

Even if they only support now Google and Facebook, you can still go to "I forgot my password" with your normal e-mail account. It won't give you any problems. I did it some weeks ago, and there was no problem. Not a gmail nor facebook account.

Comment: Didn't see that one in my panic. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to recover and now I have a new account (this one). My guess is that SO uses my GMail address since I used Google at least once.

Comment: No problem! When we panic, it usually happens! I'm glad i helped @AaronDigulla Have you tried going, for example, on Incognito tab in Chrome, as it does not save the session?

Comment: @M.K Maybe, but on Stack Overflow there is never a reason to panic. Even the most impossible account problems get worked out and resolved.

Comment: especially when someone has 6000 answers good lord that's a lot

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea what happened: Since I never logged into SO using an email address, it didn't know my address.

Then support for my ID provider was removed. So I used Google several times. That probably connected my GMail address to my old account.

When I now tried to recover my account using my main email address, SO couldn't make the connection and created a new account for me **using my old profile photo**. The fact that it did display the profile photo made me think that I was in fact getting my old account back.

Answer (score -7):

[Clear History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Te28.png)

You can clear your browser history